# Problems with data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with 3D landmarks for vertebrae of 24 species of dolphins.... originally I have several individual for each species...so I tried to create new data sets containing the meanshapes for each species and three classiffiers (species, subfamiliy and habitat). This supposedly works but when it is time for me to color a phylomorphospace based on the habitat of each species....I can get the color I've chosen for each habitat to appear on the right species and species that should be coastal are painted the same color as some oceanic ones.... and a riverine species has the same color as deepdiving species.... that is why I think I have a problem in the data frame, I do not think it is matching the right habitat with the right species....

maybe I am not matching the menshapes as I should....

I have my original data frame with procrustes coordinates and several factors, that I have imported froma CVS file (Delphinidae_clasi.cvs).....

> gdf_delph<-geomorph.data.frame(Delphinidae_GPA,SP=Delphinidae_Clasif$Sp,Subfamily=Delphinidae_Clasif$Subfamily,Habitat=Delphinidae_Clasif$Habitat)

then I had a filogeny (that I need for my analysis....

> TreeDelphinidae<- '(((((((((((Slong,Sclym),Lhose),Ddelp),Scoeu),((Satte,Sfron),(TtrunO,TtrunC))),Schin),Sfluv),((((Pelec,Fatte),Gmacro),Ggris),Sbred)),((((Ccomm,Chect),((L. aust, Lcruc),Cheav)),Lobsc),Liper)),Lalbi),Lacut);'
> Delphinidae_phy<-read.tree(text=TreeDelphinidae)

Then I subdivide my original data set by obtaining meanshapes for each species....

> Y1 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Lacut")])

> Y2 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Lalbi")])

> Y3 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Ccomm")])

> Y4 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Cheav")])

> Y5 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Chect")])

> Y6<- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Laust")])

> Y7 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Lcruc")])

> Y8 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Lipero")])

> Y9 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Lobsc")])

> Y10 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Fatte")])

> Y11 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Ggris")])

> Y12 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Gmacro")])

> Y13 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Pelec")])

> Y14 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Sbred")])

> Y15 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Lhose")])

> Y16 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Satte")])

> Y17 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Schin")])

> Y18 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Ddelp")])

> Y19 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Sclym")])

> Y20 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Scoeu")])

> Y21 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Sfluv")])

> Y22 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Sfron")])

> Y23 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "Slong")])

> Y24 <- mshape(gdf_delph$coords[,,which(gdf_delph$SP == "TtrunC")])

> YT <- array(c(Y24, Y23, Y22, Y21, Y20, Y19, Y18, Y17, Y16, Y15, Y14, Y13, Y12, Y11, Y10, Y9, Y8, Y7, Y6, Y5, Y4, Y3, Y2,Y1 ), dim = c(35,3,25), dimnames = list(c(),c(),Delphinidae_phy$tip.label))

The I add a new .csv file with three factors and as many row as species I have (mean_Clasif.csv) and create the new data frame.....

> meanshape_gdf<-geomorph.data.frame(coords=YT, SP=mean_Clasif$Sp,Subfamily=mean_Clasif$Subfamily,Habitat=mean_Clasif$Habitat,Phy= Delphinidae_phy)

I obtain a new dataframe with the correct number of observations and classifiers but when I try to plot it using different colors for the seven levels of the factor habitat... I can not get to color the species with the right color.....

I am sorry if the question is too basic.... I am struggling trying to learn to use Studio...and I am losing the battle

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi  and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post some of the graphing code that's giving you difficulty with colors? It might be good, too, to provide a small sample of the data.frame you're graphing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.